# How to filter out device info from `usb-devices` using VID & PID?

Tags: command-line, bash

To answer questions regarding USB devices here and sending kernel patches, I need output of `usb-devices` command.

Or more full `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices`.

But it gives a lot of output regarding all devices.

What is the easiest way to filter out only section regarding one device, if I know `Vendor` and `ProdID`.

Separators of sections are blank lines.

It should look like this

```
T:  Bus=04 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=046d ProdID=c05a Rev=63.00
S:  Manufacturer=Logitech
S:  Product=USB Optical Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
```

or

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04b8 ProdID=0898 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=EPSON
S:  Product=EPSON XP-402 403 405 406 Series
S:  SerialNumber=51464B593030343135
C:* #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=  2mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:* If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=07(print) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usblp
E:  Ad=04(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=85(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
I:* If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=07(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=88(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
```

And also when there are more that one records with same Vendor ID, I'd like to have empty line separators in output too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the records are separated by blank lines, it should be possible to use `awk` or `perl` in *paragraph mode* e.g.

```
sudo awk -vRS= '/Vendor=04b8/{print $0,"\n"}' /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
```

or (with GNU awk)

```
sudo awk -vRS= '/Vendor=04b8/{print $0,RT}' /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
```

or with perl

```
sudo perl -00 -ne 'print if /Vendor=1d6b/' /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices
```

If your system has the `usb-devices` utility, you may be able to avoid `cat`ing the file directly:

```
usb-devices | awk '/1d6b/{print $0,RT}' RS=
```

Comment: This is perfect when there is one record with a Vendor ID. But if there are more than one, it gives correct output, but misses separators. Is there a way to keep empty line between blocks?

Comment: @Pilot6 if you have GNU awk, you could maybe try using the `RT` special variable e.g. `gawk -vRS= -vORS= '/Vendor=1d6b/{print $0,RT}'`

Comment: `usb-devices |  awk '/1d6b/{print $0,RT}' RS=` or just awk with same pattern to a file does the job. Will you explain what it means pls?

Comment: @Pilot6 the variable `RT` just contains the value that matched the corresponding `RS`: in this case, it's overkill really (since we know it is a newline); probably `{print $0, "\n"}` would do as well, and be more portable (although it will print an additional newline if the matching record happens to be at the end of the input, I think).

Comment: @steeldriver I edited your answer. You can update it with perl variant. I have no idea how to do it in perl.

Comment: @Pilot6 I would prefer if you had submitted (and accepted, if you wish) your own answer rather than substantially editing mine

Comment: @steeldriver  I also hate when my answers are edited. Sorry for that. You can rollback if you wish. But anyway big thanks!